# How can I stop emacs from indenting javascript comment lines differently based on the characters in previous comment lines?

Tags: javascript, emacs

I am using version 23.1.1 of emacs (unfortunately not upgradable), and run emacs within putty by using 'emacs -nw',

When editing JavaScript files, emacs has some very annoying behavior when it comes to indenting comment lines.  Examples:

If one comment line contains a question mark (or colon), then the next line is auto-indented an additional 4 spaces:

```
// is this the right thing to do here?
    // check if foo=bar
```

If one comment line contains a closing parenthesis then the next comment line is auto-indented 4 spaces fewer:

```
    // When foo == bar, we do 2 things
    // 1) something
// 2) something else
```

There are other similar examples.  Basically emacs is treating the comments as code and is indenting based on the symbols included.  Is there a way to disable this?  I think the simplest description of the correct behavior is to auto-indent a comment line to the same level as the previous line if that is also a comment line.

Comment: The answer will depend on what mode emacs is using for javascript files. I believe Emacs 23 came with `js-mode`, but there are other possibilities. You can find out by looking at the modeline for the buffer, and by looking at the mode help with `C-h m`.